# How to count number of unique buyers in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, worksheet-function, microsoft-excel-2007

I am creating a workbook for sold items of my company. and I have a list of items in column O of one of my sheets.

now I want excel to count the number of total buyers and number of unique buyers.

I have to say that I divided the information of buyers into two columns. ( First Name. Last Name)

I want excel to check columns D & E which contains the first name and last name of customers and give me these totals.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You may create a column to merge first name and last name to create a column for "full name".
Then, you may follow instruction from Microsoft via link below:

*** Count unique values among duplicates ***

(Method 1) Count the number of unique values by using a filter

(Method 2) Count the number of unique values by using functions

https://support.office.com/en-in/article/Count-unique-values-among-duplicates-7889942d-824e-4469-893c-191d1efde950

Hope it helps!